# Hacer click en una foto del Carrusel y que aparezca tbm en el contenedor Principal, donde dice "Mecánica de Fluidos"

Tags: carrusel

Tengo un contenedor Principal, donde sale la imagen de fondo, el nombre del curso, detalles y algunos botones más.
Debajo, un carrusel. Lo que intento es que al hacer click en una foto del carrusel, me aparezca en el contenedor Principal y si se pudiese, la informacion que hay dentro de los botones también cambie de acuerdo al curso que escoja. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

[image: El Contenedor principal es donde dice "Mecánica de fluidos"]

Código HTML

```
    <div  class="curso-principal">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <h3 class="titulo">Mecánica de Fluidos</h3>
            <p class="descripción">
                Narra las aventuras de un grupo de exploradores que hacen uso de un agujero de gusano recientemente descubierto para superar las limitaciones de los viajes espaciales tripulados y vencer las inmensas distancias que tiene un viaje interestelar. 
            </p>
            <button id="btn-abrir-popup"  class="boton"><i class="fas fa-play"> </i>Reproducir</button>
            <button role="button" class="boton"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>Más información</button>
            <button role="button" class="boton"><i class="fas fa-list"></i>Regístrate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="cursos-recomendados contenedor">
            <div class="contenedor-titulo-controles">
                <h3>Cursos de la Semana</h3>
                <div class="indicadores"></div>
            </div>

<div class="contenedor-principal">
                <button role="button" id="flecha-izquierda" class="flecha-izquierda"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></button>

<div class="contenedor-carousel">
                    <div class="carousel">
                        <div class="pelicula">
                            <a href="#arriba"><img src="https://curso-carrusel-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
```